# Azure Fucntion external Api - Error: No such host is known

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I'm encountering an issue while trying to consume an external API within an Azure Function. The error message I'm receiving is "No such host is known (*******..com: 443)" and the stack trace points to several System.Net.Http methods.

Stack Trace:

```
No such host is known. (*******..com: 443). Stack Trace: at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I've verified that the URL is correct and accessible from other environments (LOCAL). What could be causing this issue within the Azure Function context? Any insights or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I've tried to bypass the certificate using asp.net core but no result

Comment: Is your function on a VNET?

Comment: No,  using Y1 Consumption plan

Answer (score 0):

> No such host is known. (*******..com: 443). Stack Trace: at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

- Double-check that the External API URL is accessible and has no typos or missing characters.
- Check the values passing to the parameters in the API URL are valid and allowed
- Create an Azure function in local and access the external API from the function and deploy it to Azure Function App in Portal.

**I have created a Http triggered Azure function and used below code to call the External API and it worked as expected.**

- I'm using https://www.weatherapi.com/ as External API in the Function.

```cs
 public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
     [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
     ILogger log)
 {
     log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

     const string apiKey = "<API_KEY>"; 
     string location = req.Query["location"]; 
     log.LogInformation($"req location: {location}");

     string url = $"http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key={apiKey}&q={location}&aqi=no";
     log.LogInformation($"url: {url}");

     // Initiating http call with api
     var client = new HttpClient();
     var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

     // Handling the response
     var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     dynamic responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

     string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(json)
         ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully!! "
                 : $"This HTTP triggered function executed successfully! \n weatherstack json response is \n {json}";
     return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
 }
```

**Console Response:**

```cs
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5530 Commit hash: N/A +c8883e7f3c06e2b424fbac033806c19d8d91418c (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.28.5.21962

[2024-02-23T16:02:10.621Z] Found C:\Users\uname\OneDrive - Microsoft\Desktop\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.

Functions:

        Function1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7017/api/Function1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-02-23T16:02:19.763Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-02-23T16:02:23.527Z] Executing 'Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=bb942336-1d68-4614-b4aa-5c6f6dcbc735)
[2024-02-23T16:02:23.561Z] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-02-23T16:02:23.565Z] req location: London
[2024-02-23T16:02:23.568Z] url: http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=0bbd6c70006848bdad8132333242302&q=London&aqi=no
[2024-02-23T16:02:58.989Z] Executed 'Function1' (Succeeded, Id=bb942336-1d68-4614-b4aa-5c6f6dcbc735, Duration=35501ms)
```

**Local Response:**

[image]

- Deployed the function to Azure Function App with Consumption Plan(Y1) and able to call the external API from Function App in Portal:

**Portal:**
Passing Location as query parameter:

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've already debugged my function in my local enviroment and it's works fine, it can reach the api endpoint and retireive the data. 

The problem is when i deploy the function to azure and try to trigger it i got always the error No such host is known

Comment: Can you try publishing to a new function app?

Comment: Always same error !

Comment: Can you try to implement the steps I have given and check if it leads to the same error.